# How to extend the speaking time at webkit SpeechRecognition? No break after a short pause in speech

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I only use speech recognition after clicking a button. Therefore the `recognition.continuous = false` is set. Note from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/

> The continuous property of the SpeechRecognition interface controls
> whether continuous results are returned for each recognition, or only
> a single result.

Now when I speak something, e.g. This is a nice source code {take a pause of 1-2 seconds} it breaks off at this point.

How can I extend the speaking time? I think a break after 3-5 seconds is ok.

PS: The code may not run here due to security issues. Therefore, please take a look at https://codepen.io/durrrrr/pen/RwaRVdg

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
      function(stream) {
         console.log("Microphone Access supported");
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("An error occured by accessing the microphone: " + err.name);
      }
    );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}


window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;

if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {

    console.log('Speech recognition supported');

    var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
    var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList;

    // JSpeech Grammar Format
    var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = aqua | azure | beige | bisque | black | blue | brown | chocolate | coral | crimson | cyan | fuchsia | ghostwhite | gold | goldenrod | gray | green | indigo | ivory | khaki | lavender | lime | linen | magenta | maroon | moccasin | navy | olive | orange | orchid | peru | pink | plum | purple | red | salmon | sienna | silver | snow | tan | teal | thistle | tomato | turquoise | violet | white | yellow ;'
    var message = $('#message');
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
    var finalTranscript = '';
    speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1)
    recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
    recognition.lang = 'en-EN';
    recognition.interimResults = true; 
    recognition.continuous = false;

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      var currentTranscript = '';
      var confidenceFinalTranscrip = '';
      for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        if(event.results[i].isFinal) {
          finalTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
          confidenceFinalTranscrip = event.results[i][0].confidence;
          $('#finalTranscript').html(finalTranscript);
        } else {
          currentTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
      }
      $('#currentTranscript').html(currentTranscript);
    };
  
    recognition.onspeechend = function() {
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone').removeClass('pulse-ring');
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone').removeClass('pulse-ring-small');
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone-font').removeClass('pulse-ring-font-on').addClass('pulse-ring-font-off');
      recognition.stop();
    };

    recognition.onerror = function(event) {
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone').removeClass('pulse-ring');
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone-font').removeClass('pulse-ring-font-on').addClass('pulse-ring-font-off');
      $('#errorTranscript').html(event.speechError);
    }

} else {
  console.log('Speech recognition not supported');
}

$('#btnStartSpeech').on('click', function(){
  $('#pulse-ring-microphone').addClass('pulse-ring');
  $('#pulse-ring-microphone-font').removeClass('pulse-ring-font-off').addClass('pulse-ring-font-on');
  recognition.start();
});
```

```css
.container-pulse-ring {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-pulse-ring:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 0px;
}

#btnStartSpeech.btnAnimated {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #337ab7;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
}

.btnAnimated:focus {
  outline: 0px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}

.pulse-ring-font-on {
  color: #fff;
}

.pulse-ring-font-off {
  color: #333;
}

.pulse-ring {
  content: '';
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 50px solid #337ab7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  animation: pulsate infinite 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true },
      function(stream) {
         console.log("Accessed the Microphone");
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occured: " + err.name);
      }
    );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}


window.SpeechRecognition = window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;

if ('SpeechRecognition' in window) {

    console.log('Speech recognition supported');

    var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;

    // JSpeech Grammar Format
    var message = $('#message');
    var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
    var finalTranscript = '';
    recognition.lang = 'en-EN';
    recognition.interimResults = true; 
    recognition.continuous = false;

    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      var currentTranscript = '';
      var confidenceFinalTranscrip = '';
      for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
        if(event.results[i].isFinal) {
          finalTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
          confidenceFinalTranscrip = event.results[i][0].confidence;
          $('#finalTranscript').html(finalTranscript);
        } else {
          currentTranscript += event.results[i][0].transcript;
        }
      }
      $('#currentTranscript').html(currentTranscript);
    };
  
    recognition.onspeechend = function() {
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone').removeClass('pulse-ring');
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone').removeClass('pulse-ring-small');
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone-font').removeClass('pulse-ring-font-on').addClass('pulse-ring-font-off');
      recognition.stop();
    };

    recognition.onerror = function(event) {
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone').removeClass('pulse-ring');
      $('#pulse-ring-microphone-font').removeClass('pulse-ring-font-on').addClass('pulse-ring-font-off');
      $('#errorTranscript').html(event.speechError);
    }

} else {
  console.log('Speech recognition not supported');
}

$('#btnStartSpeech').on('click', function(){
  $('#pulse-ring-microphone').addClass('pulse-ring');
  $('#pulse-ring-microphone-font').removeClass('pulse-ring-font-off').addClass('pulse-ring-font-on');
  recognition.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could running a setTimeout to restart the recognition start

```
setTimeout(() => {
      recognition.start();
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`recognition.continuous = false` means that the service stops as soon as the first final result appears. The internal VAD (voice activity detection) will decide when your input stopped. Its pretty aggressive and you cannot change the threshold, so after 1-2s of no speech it will always end.

You can set the engine to `continuous = true` and collect multiple final results until some max. time is reached (I'm using this for SEPIA open-source voice assistant), but state handling can be quite tricky.

I'm currently building a library that resembles the Web Speech API with modules for open-source VAD and speech recognition ([SEPIA Web Audio Library](https://github.com/SEPIA-Framework/sepia-web-audio)), giving you full control over every aspect, but you'll need to host your own ASR server ... ^^

Answer (score 0):

update your code with recognition.continue = false
to

```
continue = true
```